# Storing values in an array session - array only storing most recent value

Tags: php, arrays

```
$user = hobaa;
$usernames = array();
$usernames['name'] = $user;


print_r($usernames['name']);
```

Will issue something like

```
Array ( [name] => hobaa )
```

and `print_r($usernames);` will issue this out `hobaa`

**How can I make it save multiple values?**

Tried

```
$users = array("hobaa","test");
foreach($users as $user) {
    $usernames = array();
    $usernames['name'][] = $user;
   }
    print_r($usernames['name']);
```

But it just takes the last value.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Because you're resetting the array on every iteration `$usernames = array();`.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed and works fine!

Answer (score 1):

From this code:

```
foreach($users as $user) {
    $usernames = array();
    $usernames['name'][] = $user;
   }
```

remove this line from loop:

```
$usernames = array();
```

and put it above the loop like:

```
$usernames = array();
foreach($users as $user) {
    $usernames['name'][] = $user;
   }
```

and try again. As you are `re-initializing` the array on every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$users = array("hobaa","test");
// a new usernames array to use
$usernames = array();
// 
foreach($users as $user) {
    array_push($usernames, $user);
}

print_r($usernames);
```

Will give:

```
Array ( [0] => hobaa [1] => test )
```

Answer (score 0):

Define `$usernamse` variable outside of the loop. Use the following code  :

```
$users = array("hobaa","test");
$usernames = array();
foreach($users as $user) {
    $usernames['name'][] = $user;
}
print_r($usernames['name']);
```